# How to check if jQuery, $ is called with a specific selector in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

My Code:

```
$('#test1').val('string1');
```

I'm able to test if **val** has been called with **'string1'**.

```
spyOn($.fn, 'val');

expect($.fn.val).toHaveBeenCalledWith('string1');
```

But I want to test if $ has been called with a specific selector. I want to be able to do this.

```
expect($.fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('#test1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery script (version 3.5.1), I found that the function that handles the selector is `$.fn.init`

```
 jQuery.fn.init = function( selector, context, root ) {...}
```

That is at line # 3133.

So your Jasmine `expect` would be:

```
expect($.fn.init).toHaveBeenCalledWith('#test1', undefined, jasmine.anything());
```

---

You can ignore some arguments. [Reference](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Matching_existence_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.anything%3C/code%3E)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. It threw an error. But I just had to add undefined and jasmine.anything() as the additional 2 parameters. 

**Error**: Expected spy init to have been called with:
          [ '#test1' ]
        but actual calls were:
          [ '#test1', undefined, <anonymous>({ 0: HTMLNode, context: HTMLNode, length: 1 }) ]

Comment: I edited accordingly ;) Can you accept the answer (green checkmark) ?