# How to write Jasmine unit test for jQuery datatables AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, datatable, mocking, jasmine

I am using jQuery Datatables in my current project and I want to unit test that using Jasmine, however my test is failing. I'm new to writing Jasmine. Any guidance is appreciated.

```js
function loadFacilityAlertsDrillDown() {
  var dataTableControls = "FacilityAlert";
  $('#FacilityAlert').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "info": true,
    "stateSave": false,
    "lengthMenu": [
      [5, 30, 40, 50, 100],
      [5, 30, 40, 50, 100]
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 30,
    "searchDelay": 1000,
    "ajax": {
      "url": baseUrl + "/Report/GetFacilityAlertsDrillDown",
      "type": "POST",
      "data": {
        ACOKey: $("#CurrentUserAcoIds").val(),
        ProgramType: reportParameters.programType,
        StartDate: reportParameters.startDate
      },
      error: function(errorData) {
        bootbox.alert(errorData.statusText);
      }
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "OppBandDiv",
        render: function(data, type, row) {
          return data;
        },
        "orderable": true
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe [that helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850758/2159528)... You did not post your Jasmine code.

Comment: I did'nt write the jasmine code.